# Eclipse Juno - MainActivity won't create/ missing AVD

Tags: android, eclipse

So I'm back into the "I want to create an app" mode so I downloaded Eclipse Juno from the google developer site last night and updated most of the stuff in the Android SDK Manager. But I have two issues:

- Although I can create an android project, the MainActicity java file won't create under "src" folder. I definitely get to choose which activity I want in the project creation wizard. I have no idea why this happens.
- I really need to use a virtual device for my app development, but why does Juno has no device to select? Sometime last year, I remember the previous version had many choices for AVD and I could easily debug.

I am completely lost on this and actually installed Eclipse twice in the last two days thinking it's something I've done. Can someone guide me?

Thanks

Comment: For your second question, you need to create AVD. In eclipse, go to Window->Android virtual device manager -> new

Comment: For your first problem, I think things are not settled just yet with the most recent ADT. Just try creating the MainActivity manually. Uncheck `Create Activity` checkbox when configuring your application.

Comment: I need an AVD for an android phone. Can you please give me the parameters for a typical android phone, like S5 or Nexus etc?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/common-android-virtual-device-configurations--mobile-1574   http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_Virtual_Device_%28AVD%29

Comment: While creating project, under Create Activity Window select the template other than Tabbed Activity, Blank Activity, Blank Activity with Fragment, "Navigation Drawer Activity". I thinks in latest ADT update there is some issue with above mentioned templates. Other templates are working properly.